# Echad Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ever* [was](http://web.archive.org/web/20070816193605/www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html) 191 when *Avraham* was born.

Answer (score 1):

191 years after Avraham Avinu was told to circumcise himself and served the Malachim Yaakov Avinu arrived in Mitzrayim